# How do I monitor all Terminated messages in akka?

Tags: java, akka, scala-java-interop

I want to create an Actor which subscribes to Terminated messages for all Actors created in the system. How do I do that?

I have tried below - which does not seem to work,

```
getContext().system().eventStream().subscribe(getSelf(), Terminated.class);
```

and I would like to avoid below - because then I will need to do that for each actor I want to monitor.,

```
getContext().watch(subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar (but a bit less hacky) way to solve this would be to implement a Publish/Subscribe pattern (as described [here](http://www.benhowell.net/examples/2014/04/18/scala-and-the-akka-eventstream/) in Scala for instance)

Then you could just have your Actor subscribe to a specific event (such as "Terminated") like that:

```
EventStream.subscribe(Foo.onEvent, "Terminated")
```